# Unity car steering

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity Car Pro for car physics. I want the **car to slip** during the steering. This script is working perfect but it is so real.

Here are some images to explain my question:
[image: ...]
[image: ...]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

turn-off car steering feature and instead of steering left or right use transform.Translate(..) to move your car left or right direction. Or
Use addForce() method to apply force towards left or right.

Comment: I've tried but when I do like this, car is slipping like paper (very unrealistic). Because there is no **centrifugal force**. What I want to achive is this physics : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1kWlDlVylg

Comment: Well that is very unrealistic!

Answer (score 0):

Like what Sheheryar said, transform.Translate can do this. For example, you can use `transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);` in update and have a variable called turnSpeed. It has no rotation so it slides, just like how you want it.